issue with podman mounted directory permissions
We're trying to run RStudio Server within a podman image and running into permission problems when a user tries to login.
If I start the image with the following:
podman run -d -it -p 8787:8787 -e ROOT=false -e DISABLE_AUTH=false \
  --userns=keep-id \
  --privileged \
  --name RStudioPod  \
  -v /usr/local/RStudioPod/etc/odbc.ini:/etc/odbc.ini:ro \
  -v /usr/local/RStudioPod/etc/odbcinst.ini:/etc/odbcinst.ini:ro \
  -v /usr/local/RStudioPod/var/lib/rstudio-server:/var/lib/rstudio-server \
  -v /usr/local/RStudioPod/Users/:/home:rw \
  skcc/rhelrstudiotest:latest /usr/sbin/init

the image exits with:
Welcome to Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9.4 (Plow)!

Initializing machine ID from container UUID.
Cannot write /run/machine-id: Permission denied
Failed to write /run/systemd/container, ignoring: No such file or directory
Failed to open '/sys/firmware/dmi/entries/11-0/raw', ignoring: Permission denied
Failed to allocate manager object: No such file or directory
[!!!!!!] Failed to allocate manager object.
Exiting PID 1...

If I remove --userns=keep-id, the image starts, but I run into permission problems.
HOST: ls -l of /usr/local/RStudioPod/Users
drwxr-xr-x. 2 cmm024 cmm024  6 Nov  1 15:54 cmm024
drwxr-xr-x. 5 jpr101 jpr101 82 Nov  5 17:51 jpr101
drwxr-xr-x. 2 kxh451 kxh451  6 Nov  5 09:28 kxh451
drwxr-xr-x. 2 kys039 kys039  6 Nov  5 14:43 kys039

CONTAINER:
[root@ef343c0e5a12]# ls -l /home
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 2  12165  12165  6 Nov  1 19:54 cmm024
drwxr-xr-x. 5 root   root   82 Nov  5 22:51 jpr101
drwxr-xr-x. 2 nobody nobody  6 Nov  5 14:28 kxh451
drwxr-xr-x. 2 nobody nobody  6 Nov  5 19:43 kys039

It permits me jpr101 to login to the RStudio application, but I get permission errors if I try to save anything from within the application.
The other 3 users cannot logon to the application.
tried --userns=keep-id as suggested in other articles, but the container no longer starts with the above error.
